# Nodejs : require.paths. Restoring original paths

Tags: path, restore, node.js

I was playing around with require.paths and i modified it by mistake. How do i restore the original require.paths? Is there a command line utility to figure out what my nodejs path is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh i got it working again. Just had to restart my terminal.